# Concatenate variables in PHP

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I would like to concatenate 2 variables or a string and a variable with the following code,

```
$dir = '<img src="image_folder/"';

if ($query_Result >0) 
{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
       {
            echo $dir.$row['image_link'].'>';
```

It only echos the src path and not the $row variable. I have tried echoing out the string

`'<img src="image_folder/".$row['image_link'].'>'`

but nothing seems to work.

Can someone suggest a way round this?

Comment: If I echo out $row['image_link'] by itself it gives me the correct jpg name. But is blank when I try to concatenate

Comment: Your code is backwards.   What i mean by that is your order of operations is backwards.  you should make the query and get your result ensure your results are available as failing gracefully is way better than a random image not showing up for no apparent reason.  Then you should append the image link inside the tag as you have shown in your bottom example.  Var_dump to make sure its building the correct path and that should work.

Comment: Nope, same problem

Comment: jgetner, I know what you mean. But I was hoping for a cleaner code sequence and thought a simple concatenation wasn't going to be so complex

Comment: I added an answer that should fix ya up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($query_Result >0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo  "<img src='image_folder/".$row['image_link']."'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: jgetner, you and the rest of the stackoverflow people are too good. Thank you. What took you 2 minutes, I have been working on the whole day. Thank you again

Comment: no problem bud been there many times over myself.  I just have a 15 year head start on this stuff lol